# How to test that a function prop was called in react-testing-library

Tags: javascript, jestjs, react-testing-library

There are 3 files:

**File 1:** ***helpers.js***

```
export const helpers = () => ({
  bar: () => 'Bar was called',
});
```

**File 2:** ***TestComponent.js***

```
import React from 'react';
import { helpers } from './helpers';

const TestComponent = () => {
  const { bar } = helpers();
  return (
    <><button onClick={bar}/></>
  );
};

export default TestComponent;
```

**File 3:** ***TestComponent.test.js***

```
import React from 'react';
import userEvent from '@testing-library/user-event';
import { screen, render } from '@testing-library/react';
import TestComponent from './TestComponent';
import { helpers } from './helpers';

jest.mock('./helpers', () => ({
  helpers: jest.fn(),
}));

test('bar is called', () => {
  helpers.mockImplementation(() => ({
    bar: jest.fn(),
  }));

  render(
    <TestComponent />,
  );

  userEvent.click(screen.getByRole('button'));

  expect(???????).toHaveBeenCalled();
});
```

This line is the key:

```
expect(???????).toHaveBeenCalled();
```

**The question**: How can I test if `bar` function was called? I was expecting that something similar to `expect(helpers().bar)` would work. But it doesn't.

Comment: you are right. Thanks!

You can go ahead and a write the answer and I will accept it.

Comment: ok thanks I added my answer now

Answer (score 2, accepted):

save the function in a variable and use it in expect

```
test('bar is called', () => {
  const bar = jest.fn()
  helpers.mockImplementation(() => ({bar}));

  render(
    <TestComponent />,
  );

  userEvent.click(screen.getByRole('button'));

  expect(bar).toHaveBeenCalled();
});
```